# Number of subscriptions are increasing by each request

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new in angular and RXJS, so can't understand why the number of returned values is increasing on each request.

the service

```js
subject = new Subject<any>();

get(endpoint: string, params?: URLSearchParams) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));

  const opts: any = { headers };
  if (params != null) {
    opts.params = params;
  }
  const options = new RequestOptions(opts);

  let response = this.http.get(this.globals.apiUrl + endpoint, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((res) => {
      this.subject.next(res);
    });

  return this.subject.asObservable(); 
}
```

the component:

```js
onGetSmth(){
    this.authService.get('doors').subscribe((doors) => {
      console.log(doors)
    })
}
```

Comment: How `onGetSmth()` is invoked?

Comment: (click)="onGetSmth()"

Answer (score 0):

`Subjects` are multicast. When you do not `complete` a subject all subscriptions to the same subject will receive the same value. So every time you invoke `onGetSmth()` the previous subscription will also get the next value.

You can resolve this by removing the subject from your code and keeping it simple:

```
get(endpoint: string, params?: URLSearchParams) {
 const headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));

 const opts: any = {headers: headers};
 if (params != null) {
  opts.params = params;
 }
 const options = new RequestOptions(opts);

 return this.http.get( this.globals.apiUrl + endpoint, options)
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Every time you will invoke `get().subscribe()` this will be unicast so no sharing of values will happen. After the request is completed the subscription will now also complete properly.

Comment: The idea is I want to check the response before it is returned as observable

Comment: That is still possible, `get().do(val => console.log(val)).subscribe()`

Comment: I need to do that in the service, to avoid code duplication

Comment: its hard guessing how the code should look. You can make your `get()` private and a public `get()` containing the check logic? The problem resides in your subject construction from your question

Comment: My goal is to build a service which makes http requests. On each request i want to make some checks. If web token doesn't exist on local storage, or is invalid, we do redirect to login page.

Comment: You can still do all those checks with above mentioned solution. Unless you want to cache the http request calls you dont need to use Subjects. Keep a blind rule not to use `subscribe` inside services , use it only in components .